# how to start two animations on the same time on different activities

Tags: android, android-animation

I have two simple activities one is normal activity and the second one is translucent. The translucent above the normal one. I have to start two animations at the same time on both activities.

I am confused with timing, can any one suggest how can we achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

I am using simple translation animation on both places but timing is not matching:

```
Animation a = new ScaleAnimation(1, 1, 0, 1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
              (float) 0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float) 0);
a.setFillAfter(true);
tabLayout.setAnimation(a);
a.setDuration(400);
a.setInterpolator(new LinearOutSlowInInterpolator());
tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
tabLayout.startAnimation(a);
```

The above code I am using for the animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do such a thing, use fragments instead of Activity. Activity can easily control animations in two fragments and thus your problem can be solved easily. As mentioned in another answer also, this cannot be achieved by using activities as the animation will be destroyed once it is in background. And inter fragment communication can be achieve easily by using interfaces via the Activity class. I recommend you to read about fragments and communication between fragments.

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to start two separated animations in two different activities. The activity in the background will be destroyed once it is put there. You can start an animation only in the current visible activity.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence. The second is wrong however, especially `will be destroyed` part. The other activity may be destroyed, but does not have to. and it is fine to have i.e. activity themed as dialog so you see underlying activity, however playing any animation there may be problematic as its `onPause()` has been called already

Answer (score 1):

Try using AnimationSet for the timing.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html